# Paypal Express Checkout : Is it possible to skip login page?

Tags: paypal

I tried the paypal express checkout example with paypal NVP
Just wanted to know if it is possible to skip the login page and instead redirect directly to the page where use can simply fill the credit card number and other related information?
If this is possible can somebody please quickly give some hints to get this done??

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Ensure you include the following in your API request: LANDINGPAGE=Billing and SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole. This will allow you to credit card payments from non-registered PayPal users, without the need for them to have a PayPal account (unless you're setting up a subscription).

More fun parameters can be found at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout